# How to render file in views.py from a different directory?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a directory structure

```
templates\
     myFile1.html
     ....

somedirectory\
     myFile2.html
```

In my views.py file, in order to render *myFile1.html* I can do

```
def foo1(request):
   render(file1,'myFile1.html')
```

How can I navigate to *myFile2.html?*
I tried

```
def foo2(request):
   render(file2,'../somedirectory/myFile2.html')
```

but does not seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `somedirectory` into [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs) tuple defined in settings.py:

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ...
    '/path/to/somedirectory'
)
```

Then you can render it via `render()` in views.py:

**views.py**

```
def foo2(request):
    return render(request, 'myFile2.html', {'user': request.user})
```

Comment: Great. thank you (+1). Is it possible just to "navigate" to it?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "navigate"? Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I mean writing somehow the path render(file2,'../somedirectory/myFile2.html')

Comment: what's `file2`? BTW, you need to add `return` before `render`.

Comment: Yes, to file2.html. Yes I return it (see my initial question above)